# Print simple double value with precision

Tags: c++

Here is my code, just a basic test program to print a number with floating point, with `printf` it works great (I guess because the format is passed explicitly) but with `std::cout` I'm unable to get it right and `std::setprecision` doesn't seem to help, can you please give me a hand?

```c
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main ()
{
    std::cout << double(1999999900) / 10000 << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::setprecision(5) << double(1999999900) / 10000 << std::endl;
    printf("%f\n", double(1999999900) / 10000);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output, how can I get 199999.99 from the `std::cout` print also?

```
[root@ test00]# g++ -std=c++11 test1.cpp -o test1; ./test1
200000
2e+05
199999.990000
```

Comment: Experiment with the [floating point I/O manipulators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed).

Comment: On an unrelated note, you don't need that cast to `double`, just use a floating-point number like `1999999900.0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
std::cout << std::setprecision(5) << std::fixed << double(1999999900) / 10000  << std::endl;
```